# Sites not loading but downloading working fine

Tags: windows-7, firefox, google-chrome, internet, internet-explorer

The problem involves all three browsers I have installed on my system:

1. Google Chrome 20.0.1130.1 (up to date)
2. Mozilla Firefox 13.0 (up to date)
3. Microsoft Internet Explorer 9.0.8112.16421 (up to date)

Problems I am facing:

1. Sites not loading at all,sometimes I have to reload repeatedly to make them load
2. Sites loading but without images
3. Sites loading but without CSS or images
4. Sites like YouTube (Flash video sites) won't play videos anymore

I have tried emptying cache, deleting history, cookies, checked my DNS server address with my ISP but to no avail.

Sometimes these sites load after repeated reloading but some still do not load any CSS or images, e.g. 9gag.com

But downloading is working fine, at its rated speed, even torrents are working.

Anyone has a clue as to what is the problem? I am ruling out internet connectivity since my downloads are working fine (Also only Windows is not the culprit because I am facing the same problem on Ubuntu).

Comment: "my downloads are working fine" you mean you are torrenting during all of this?  Are you uploading?  What speed are you uploading at?  Believe it or not, this can affect the quality of your browsing (download) experience.  Are you eating up all your bandwidth with your downloading?  Have you checked your router logs to see what kind of activity is hitting your router?

Comment: no I am not torrenting(yes i am aware of the fact that it eats away the bandwidth)..I tried using google DNS, now its working fine...but I still cant figure out why downloading was working fine but sites were not loading(with my ISP DNS)

Comment: What does "downloading" include? It's a pretty broad term that refers to getting anything from another system; including web pages

Comment: I mean when I am downloading attachments or downloading any file from sites like filehippo.com, even windows update is working fine...